# Access Individual Google Maps Elements (Distance, Time, Directions)

Tags: google-maps

How do you access individual elements in Google Maps?

Is there a way to do this through the API or will I have to parse the DOM and pull the elements (e.g., distance, time, directions) separately? Version 2 or 3 of the API is fine.

Example:

```
<div jstcache="6" style="text-align: right; padding-bottom: 0.3em;"
jseval="this.innerHTML = $Route.summaryHtml">38.9&nbsp;mi (about 40 mins)</div>
```

I want just the distance (e.g., 38.9 mi) for a Javascript calculation.  If nothing exists in the API, I'll parse it out manually.

Thanks,
Mark

Note: This is the full example site I'm using:  http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/apis/maps/documentation/examples/directions-advanced.html

**Update with simplified solution**:

For those that need it, here is a very simple full HTML page that I was able to thin out from the example that Cannonade posted. This has all styling and other scripts removed:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2.x&a…; type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    function initialize() 
    {
        alert("loading ..."); 
        if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) 
        { 
            var wp = new Array (); 
            wp[0] = new GLatLng(32.742149,119.337218); 
            wp[1] = new GLatLng(32.735347,119.328485); 
            directions = new GDirections(); directions.loadFromWaypoints(wp);
            GEvent.addListener(directions, "load", function() 
            { 
                alert(directions.getDuration().seconds); 
            }); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            alert("Sorry, the Google Maps API is not compatible with this browser"); 
        } 
    }

    </script>  
    </head>  
    <body onload="initialize();" onunload="GUnload();"></body> 
</html>
```

Put the codesamples into index.html and you'll be set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You you can get the individual properties of a [GDirections](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GDirections)::[loadFromWaypoints](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GDirections.loadFromWaypoints) request in the response.

- [getDuration](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GDirections.getDuration) - The duration in seconds for the travel time.
- [getDistance](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GDirections.getDistance) - The distance in meters or a localized string describing the distance.

You can find an example of getting the travel time [here](http://www.cannonade.net/geo.php?test=geo6) ([src](http://www.cannonade.net/geo6.js)).

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks for taking the time to post the solution.

For those that need it, here is a very simple full HTML page that I was able to thin out from the example that Cannonade posted.  This has all styling and other scripts removed:

Comment: <html>
 <head>
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2.x&amp;key=ABQIAAAAZcKXgPBBWMrwFnFDZk04exT2yXp_ZAY8_ufC3CFXhHIE1NvwkxTwfcmSfFl5Pl_HRASjiXXG_hSbEQ" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
   function initialize() {
    alert("loading ...");
  
    if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
     var wp = new Array ();
     wp[0] = new GLatLng(32.742149,119.337218);
     wp[1] = new GLatLng(32.735347,119.328485);
     directions = new GDirections();
     directions.loadFromWaypoints(wp);

Comment: GEvent.addListener(directions, "load", function() {
       alert(directions.getDuration().seconds);
       });
    }
    else {
      alert("Sorry, the Google Maps API is not compatible with this browser");
    }
    }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="initialize();" onunload="GUnload();">

 </body>
</html>

Comment: Put the top two codesamples into index.html and you'll be set.

Mark